# Artificial Gravity on board the ISS and its derivatives

Tags: iss, space-station, artificial-gravity

Was the implementation of artificial gravity ever seriously considered for use on board the ISS and its derivatives? If not, why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, as far as the ISS is concerned, there were at least two such projects in the past that I know of:

- [ISS centrifuge demonstration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus-X#ISS_centrifuge_demonstration) as part of the Nautilus-X (Non-Atmospheric Universal Transport Intended for Lengthy United States Exploration)
- [Centrifuge Accommodations Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifuge_Accommodations_Module) that was designed for NASA by JAXA

None of these seem to be going anywhere, for now, but you can say that they were *seriously considered*. The latter (CAM) was even partially built and is now sitting as a sad reminder to budgetary cuts and plan changes as administrations change at the Tsukuba Space Center's outdoor exhibit.

There were also some non-related to the station proposals, such as Zubrin's [Mars (Semi-) Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Direct#Revisions) variants that suggest rotating a tethered formation using a spent upper stage as counterbalance mass, and Nautilus-X on its own as MMSEV (Multi-Mission Space Exploration Vehicle). There might be many more similar concepts under consideration that I can't think of now. Of course, there are always the ["space wheel" stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_wheel_space_station) that popup in various discussions, but I'm not aware of any being *seriously considered* (whatever that means, let's settle for some significant money being raised or spent on it) for the time being.