# Artifical Gravity central core

Tags: gravity

so have read about the centrifugal acceleration to create artificial gravity. Being mindful of the limitations of getting objects into space, the question is more curiosity. Is it possible to work from the inside out, i.e. like the earths core works, having a spinning mass at the centre of a craft of significate weight to create gravity, rather than large external forces creating the centrifugal force. e.g. a metal core, using magnets to spin it in a liquid solution. 1) would this even work, 2) if it worked would it have a similar or lesser effect than traditional method and 3) if it works, would the two in conjunction create a better gravitational environment. (excluding the issue of getting a working solid mass of this nature into space in the first place)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there no spacecraft rotating for artificial gravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/why-are-there-no-spacecraft-rotating-for-artificial-gravity) - The differences versus **real** gravity: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34156/20766, and the practicality / cost: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1308/20766 https://space.stackexchange.com/q/281/20766

Comment: Earth's gravity is not caused by the movement of liquid in the core, you are thinking of the magnetic field. Gravity is a force created by mass, not by motion. Larger mass, more gravity. You have to have something planet size to have any significant amount of gravity. Artificial gravity on the other hand is created by acceleration. Either acceleration in a straight line like when thrusting with a rocket, or in a circle when being spun around like in a centrifuge, which causes constant change in direction thus constant acceleration. But only the object that is moving "feels" artificial gravity.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how your proposed scheme works. Can you explain what the spinning has to do with creating gravity? What is the purpose of the magnets?

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be misunderstanding the "create gravity" portion of rotational gravity schemes.

"Centrifugal acceleration" is just an object's inertia, but viewed from that object's point of view as it rotates around something.  In most centrifugal gravity schemes, the force being provided on a human inside is just centripetal force from the floor of the rotating chamber.  There isn't an "artificial gravity field" being produced that would let you attract things from the center of a craft--physical contact is required.

The amount of "gravity" felt can also change based on how you move in these centrifugal gravity situations--for example, a high speed train in a typical centrifugal gravity ring design could easily double the felt "gravity" when traveling in the same direction the ring spins, and entirely cancel it out when traveling in the opposite direction.  (The generic term for this effect in rotating frames is "[coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force)".

The [artificial-gravity tag](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-gravity) has a load of information that would be useful to you to read.

One more thing as I reread your question: in centrifugal gravity, out (away from the center of rotation) is down (the apparent direction of "gravity" in the rotating frame, i.e. the direction of centrifugal force). If you're putting stuff in the center of the craft to work alongside centrifugal gravity, they'd have to generate a repulsive force.  The actual things you describe though (a spinning mass, metal core in a liquid solution etc) wouldn't generate gravity; it seems like you're confusing gravity and magnetic fields, which are not at all the same thing.